# How to mount a partition at startup for single user, and deny access for the others?

Tags: linux, permissions, filesystems, mount

I need to mount an EXT4 partition at startup but not for all users, only for my user.

If it's possible (I'm sure it is) I would like to deny all permissions from that partition for the other users.

Comment: Do the other users have root access?  If so, then all bets are off.

Comment: No, I only have root privileges

Answer (score 3):

After mounting the partition (let say `/mnt/mypart`), change the owner of the mount point so that your user (let say `myuser`) is the owner

```
$ sudo chown myuser:root /mnt/mypart
```

and give the permission to this user to access this partition using chmod:

```
$ sudo chmod 700 /mnt/mypart
```

Doing this, only `myuser` and `root` will be able to access this partition. The partition has to be mounted when you are executing these commands.